# Style not conserved from QGIS to GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld

I have a raster file with following properties :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF Files: raster.tif Size is 28185, 24579 Coordinate System is: PROJCS["Merchich / Nord Maroc",
    GEOGCS["Merchich",
        DATUM["Merchich",
            SPHEROID["Clarke 1880 (IGN)",6378249.2,293.4660212936265,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7011"]],
            TOWGS84[31,146,47,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6261"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4261"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",33.3],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-5.4],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.999625769],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",300000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26191"]] 
Origin = (792576.146099875564687,422607.153579972393345) 
Pixel Size = (0.342319261275338,-0.342319261275338) 
Metadata: AREA_OR_POINT=Area Image Structure 
Metadata:   INTERLEAVE=PIXEL 
Corner Coordinates: Upper Left  (  792576.146,  422607.154) (  2d13' 6.09"W, 34d21'55.95"N) 
                    Lower Left  (  792576.146,  414193.288) (  2d13'16.12"W, 34d17'22.95"N) 
                    Upper Right (  802224.414,  422607.154) (  2d 6'48.62"W, 34d21'46.25"N) 
                    Lower Right (  802224.414,  414193.288) (  2d 6'58.98"W, 34d17'13.25"N) 
                    Center      (  797400.280,  418400.221) ( 2d10' 2.45"W, 34d19'34.64"N) 
Band 1 Block=28185x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray   NoData Value=-9999 
Band 2 Block=28185x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined   NoData Value=-9999 
Band 3 Block=28185x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined   NoData Value=-9999
```

I'm serving my raster with GeoServer using the following style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>raster</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name/>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                      <sld:ChannelSelection>
                        <sld:RedChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">33.915</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">254.745</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:RedChannel>
                        <sld:GreenChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>2</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">33.915</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">254.745</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:GreenChannel>
                        <sld:BlueChannel>
                        <sld:SourceChannelName>3</sld:SourceChannelName>
                        <sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                          <sld:Normalize>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="algorithm">StretchToMinimumMaximum</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="minValue">0</sld:VendorOption>
                           <sld:VendorOption name="maxValue">254.745</sld:VendorOption>
                          </sld:Normalize>
                        </sld:ContrastEnhancement>
                        </sld:BlueChannel>
                      </sld:ChannelSelection>
                    </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

In QGIS it's displayed as it should be, but in GeoServer I'm getting this : 
[image]

This is how it should be : [image]

I think the problem is caused by ColorInterp=Gray which is not set in my SLD but I couldn't find how to.

Comment: Something seems to be missing from the question, or else the title (summary) seems incorrect.   Are you saying that you use exactly the same SLD in QGIS on the raster as you use to style the raster file in GeoServer, but when you call the GeoServer WMS you get a different image (colour), or are you doing some other thing in QGIS?  sorry it isn't clear

Comment: Without changing the default style of the raster in QGIS, it is displayed correctly. I exported this style, selected the contrastEnchacement values ​​and created a Geoserver compatible SLD but gives wrong color

Comment: try using just one band - probably the 1st

Comment: It didn't work, the color changed to black

Comment: The minimum value of the contrast enhancement for the blue band is different from the others. What happens if you change it to 33.915?